# C Program to make a list of perfect numbers

Tags: c, pointers, perfect-numbers

I tried to code this but I can't run it. Please help me to check what's wrong in my code. The results I want, examples:

```
The List of Perfect Number
Give me the lastest number(start from 1): 100
6 28
```

This is a **C** program that **uses pointers**:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int i, x, n, *sum;

    printf("The List of Perfect Number\n");
    printf("Give me the lastest number(start from 1):  ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    sum = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
    *sum = 0;

    for(x=1;x<=n;x++)
    {
        for(i=1; i<x; i++)
        {
            if(x%i == 0)
            {
                *sum+=i;
            }
        }
        if(*sum == x)
            printf("%d", x);
        free(sum);
     return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (‘**why isn't this code working?**’) must include the desired behaviour, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Why on earth are you `malloc`ing a single `int`?!

Comment: If you can't run it then look at what your compiler has to say!

Comment: In the compiler there's no error, but the result can't displayed. In the compiler displayed:  The List of Perfect Number Give me the lastest number(start from 1):

Comment: I use malloc to cast the pointer

Comment: @user7165705 No, you use a cast to cast the pointer. You use `malloc` to dynamically allocate memory for a single `int`, which is entirely unnecessary.

Comment: The inner loop never executes the first time around, after which `*sum != x` and nothing is output.  Then you exit your program before looping again.  This is not the only thing wrong with your program.

Comment: learn how to use the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

The good news is that you have most of the statements you need, you just have several of them in the wrong order (and toss that pointer stuff -- this is math!):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned n;

    printf("The List of Perfect Number\n");
    printf("Give me the lastest number (start from 1): ");

    (void) scanf("%u", &n);

    for (unsigned x = 1; x <= n; x++)
    {
        unsigned sum = 0;

        for (unsigned i = 1; i <= x / 2; i++)
        {
            if (x % i == 0)
            {
                sum += i;
            }
        }

        if (sum == x)
        {
            printf("%d\n", x);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The bad news is you'll not get more than four perfect numbers with code like this due to poor performance.  It's possible to compute twice as many in reasonable time (before coming up against the size limit of **C**'s integer types) but you need to approach it differently.  Specifically, read about [Mersenne primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime), and their relationship to perfect numbers, as well as the [Lucas-Lehmer test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%E2%80%93Lehmer_primality_test) for Mersenne numbers.  It takes more thought, but, surprisingly, not too much more code.